# Why connect from react-redux doesn't send the new state as props to the my component?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I am following the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyavQ5Q015U&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9iWstfXntcj8f-dFZ4UtlN3&index=19) of `firebase` on The Net Ninja Youtube channel, and i face a problem in connecting the data from `store` in `Redux` to my component, i understand that the data will come from `firestore` asynchronously not immediately, so i assume that `props.projects` swill start as `[]`, then after some time it will change to the real data from `firestore`, state changes successfully in `mapStateToProps` when logging `state.firestore.ordered.projects` but this never happen when logging `props.projects` despite using connect from react-redux, i really don't know why this happens:

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import ProjectList from '../Projects/ProjectList';
import Notifications from './Notifications';

function Dashboard(props) {
    console.log('p', props.projects)
    return (
        <div className="dashboard container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s12 m6">
                  <ProjectList projects={props.projects} />
                </div>
                <div className="col s12 m5 offset-ml">
                    <Notifications />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state.firestore.ordered.projects)
    return {
        projects: state.firestore.ordered.projects || []
    }
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    firestoreConnect([{collection: 'Projects'}])
)(Dashboard);
```

**projectAction.js:**

```
export const createProject = (project) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        firestore.collection('Projects').add({
            ...project,
            createdAt: new Date()
        }).then(() => dispatch({
            type: 'CREATE_PROJECT',
            project
        })).catch(err => dispatch({
            type: 'CREATE_ERROR',
            err
        }))
    }
}
```

Why connect doesn't work here and don't bind data to the component once is changing??

Comment: To be clear, in `mapStateToProps` you're seeing `state.firestore.ordered.projects` update from nothing to an array of documents in Firebase, but in `Dashboard` you're not seeing `props.projects` update with the same values?

Comment: Yes, this exactly what i am experiencing here @BlunderingPhilosopher

Comment: I think if your collection has capital P (`Projects`), you should be accessing `state.firestore.ordered.Projects` (notice the capital P). Other than this, I don't see anything wrong :/

Answer (score 1):

Initially the prop `projects` is empty.But by the time the data is fetched from the firestore, the component has already been rendered. So to update it use `useEffect` and put `props.projects` as the dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {}, [props.projects])
```

Comment: Try `useEffect` hook in the **Dashboard** or the **ProjectList** component.

Comment: Also if this answers your question you can mark it as answered.